# Tensor product of operator and ket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra

I'm a mathematician only somewhat familiar with bracket notation.

Suppose I wish to write $A\otimes v$ in braket notation, where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product, $A$ is a matrix, and $v$ is vector.
If $A$ were also a vector, I believe it's standard to write $|u\rangle | v\rangle$, $|u\rangle \otimes | v\rangle$, or $|u,v\rangle$.

Can I write $A\otimes |v\rangle$? And then what if I want to multiply and operator by this vector? I guess this doesn't come up commonly in physics, because the only related question I could find is [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/385381/tensor-product-between-a-density-matrix-and-a-ket-vector) which got downvoted.

The motivation is to write $(A\otimes v)^TB (A\otimes v)?$ which is a more compact form of a certain double sum I have.

Comment: It comes up quite frequently and usage of notation is malleable to fit the specific problem at hand.  I’ve seen all of your 3 versons in use in different contexts.

Comment: I'm specifically asking about the matrix-vector version though which seems less common.

Comment: You could always consider using Penrose graphical notation. It is probably not what you're looking for, but it's meant specifically for tensor products of any multilinear objects. A tensor produt in this notation is just any two blobs drawn on the same page: https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00006

Comment: How is the matrix-vector version fundamentally different from a vector-vector version?  Presumably your matrix is an element of a vector space...

Comment: Well mathematically it's not different, but for physics notation it sort of is because I've only ever seen tensor products of kets before

Comment: a ket is just an element of a vector space so I’m not sure why you can’t use it for a matrix if it is also an element of a vector space….  Why not write $\vert A; v\rangle$?

Comment: That's why I'm asking the question. Bras, kets, and the operators are all elements of (different) vector spaces. But they distinct in braket notation.

Comment: Well… best of luck.  I have *no idea* why or how you find a problem there…

Answer (score 1):

$X = A\otimes |v\rangle$ is probably suitable if you define the (separate) spaces in which $A$ and $|v\rangle$ live.

Or in Einstein summation notation, you could write $X^{ik}_{j} = A^{i}_{j} \;v^k$.

Or in Penrose / tensor network notation, you could draw this:[image]

[Tensor networks in a nutshell](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00006) is a great introduction to this notation in the context of quantum information theory.